# The rights of an Azure AD admin on a machine enrolled in organization

Tags: entra-id

The question is short, what can the Azure administrator (with active directory) do in my machine? Is the same answer for an OSX machine?

I work for a company that wants to make our computers fully managed. We work remotely and suddenly I have questions in terms of privacy. From what I understand the admin can run commands as root, so potentially do whatever he wants. Is it true ? If so I will just leave the company, I do not wish to work with a permanent eye on me

Comment: Is the computer owned by the company? If so, then why do you care? You're only using the company computer for work related to your job, right?

Comment: @joeqwerty I don't understand your answer, I ask what can do the administrator? 
The rest isn't your the subject. If you agree that your admin and boss can spy you at home ok, not me.
And in more the law don't allow such spy/track in company, maybe in your country yes not in mine.
If you can run command as admin they can just turn on microphone, check your cam, turn on the wifi every time etc etc. Your answer it's ok if you work for police army or it's a computer in one school and maybe why not inside the office of some comapnies, but at home no ... I'm sure almost everyone agree with me...

Comment: @joeqwerty And in any case I already took my decision if they can spy I leave, I want just the answer to my question "The rights of an Azure AD admin on a machine enrolled in organization"
to know if I leave or not

Answer (score 0):

**On a Windows machine:** the Global Admin is added to the machine local admins group, so they get all the powers of a local admin: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/assign-local-admin#how-it-works

**On OSX:** there is no such thing as Azure AD Joined for OSX: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/36020725-implement-the-ability-to-join-mac-os-x-to-azure-ad

Comment: Thanks for your answer, apparently the admin will add himself to the local admins groups on OSX (I don't know how).

Comment: Guess this can be done using Intune or JAMF, but not out of the box like Windows 10.